# Exposure with an unused tag

Tags: support, tags

I have a question that fits a certain tag, but the problem is there are 4 questions on that tag and I'm worried no one will see my question... Can people only see questions in tags they browse? Or will my question appear in the general `Questions` page?
Also, if I tag with more than one tag, is my exposure getting less and less or more and more, is it an OR gate between the tags, or an AND gate?

Thanks.

Comment: In short: don't have it as the only tag, adding the language tag is crucial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of what you tag your question with, your question will still be shown in the **list at /questions** and on the **home page** (except Stack Overflow where it'll only be shown if the system thinks your question is interesting).

People who follow a tag that you have tagged your question with will see your question highlighted in the questions list.

> [image]
>
> Example of a highlighted question on Ask Different. I am following the mavericks tag, therefore questions containing that tag is highlighted.

Tagging your question with more than one tag will increase the visibility of your question, both to those who may be following that tag and also those who visit the /questions/tagged/<tag> page. A user does not need to be following all the tags that you have tagged your question with for the question to be highlighted.